# How to model tabular data that changes over time and be able to refer back to any point

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

*Note: This was tagged as SQL as well because I am completely open to a possible scripted option outside of MVC*

I have a C# MVC Razor project using Entity Framework, Code First / MySQL

## Imagine this scenario:

```
public class RelationshipStatus
{
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

Last month status was "single" and this month it's "taken".

## How should I structure this so that I can:

- ## Get RelationshipStatus with last month's date and see what it was then.
- ## Get a timeline of all changes to RelationshipStatus.

This project has many tables, but very few entries and only a handful of users.  I am more concerned with specificity than performance with this solution.

**What I've tried and ideas so far:**

- SQL Triggers to catch table updates and post them to a logging table.
- Overriding SaveChanges() to insert my own logging code.
- Using Tracker-Enabled-DBContext, which gave an error that the owner has said will never be fixed.
- Create EntityID, VersionID and date for each model.  Insert a new row instead of updating on edits and increment the VersionID.

Comment: On sql side look at temporal databases, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [event sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html)? It's usually used with [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#Relationship_to_other_ideas):

> An architectural pattern which warrants that your entities (as per Eric Evans’ definition) do not track their internal state by means of direct serialization or O/R mapping, but by means of reading and committing events to an event store. Where ES is combined with CQRS and DDD, aggregate roots are responsible for thoroughly validating and applying commands (often by means having their instance methods invoked from a Command Handler), and then publishing a single or a set of events which is also the foundation upon which the aggregate roots base their logic for dealing with method invocations. Hence, the input is a command and the output is one or many events which are transactionally (single commit) saved to an event store, and then often published on a message broker for the benefit of those interested (often the views are interested; they are then queried using Query-messages). When modeling your aggregate roots to output events, you can isolate the internal state event further than would be possible when projecting read-data from your entities, as is done in standard n-tier data-passing architectures. One significant benefit from this is that tooling such as axiomatic theorem provers (e.g. Microsoft Contracts or CHESS) are easier to apply, as the aggregate root comprehensively hides its internal state. Events are often persisted based on the version of the aggregate root instance, which yields a domain model that synchronizes in distributed systems around the concept of optimistic concurrency

With event sourcing, you can track all changes to your aggregates, and see the exact state that your object was on a specific date/version.